# How to drop primary key from table in my sql using concat function

Tags: mysql

I have tried with the below my sql statement to drop primary key in my sql.
Here, test is the d.b. name. tbl is the table name, form_id is the column name

```
 SET @PKDrop =CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `' ,test,'`.`',tbl,'` MODIFY form_id INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY');
           PREPARE PKDrop FROM @PKDrop;
           EXECUTE PKDrop;
           DEALLOCATE PREPARE PKDrop;
```

Getting error => `SET @PKDrop =CONCAT('ALTER TABLE` ' ,test,'`.`',tbl,' `MODIFY id INT NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY') Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'`

How to set fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test.tbl should also be treated as a string

```
SET @PKDrop = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' ,'`test`.`tbl`', ' MODIFY form_id INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY');
```

Comment: Thank you it is worked. can you fix this query SET @PKDrop = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' ,'`dbName`.`prefix,'_forms_',suffix`', ' MODIFY form_id INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY');?

Comment: Added prefix & postfix in the column @Aurangzeb

Comment: CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ' ,'dbName.prefix','_forms_','suffix', ' MODIFY form_id INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY');

Comment: hi, i got error with the above command. error =>  Table 'dbName.prefix_forms_suffix' doesn't exist. can you help to solve this issue? @Aurangzeb

Comment: I got it. this is the answer =>  SET @PKDrop = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `' ,dbName,'`.`',prefix,'_forms_',suffix,'` MODIFY form_id INT(11) NOT NULL, DROP PRIMARY KEY');